# The three schema of the database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, entity-relationship

I have created a database in Access and right know i have to write a report.
I know that the databasesystem has three forms of schemas: physical, conceptual and external.

Does the following ER diagram (by using the method **normalization**) belongs to the conceptual level?:

[image]

Or does this belong to the conceptual level?(incl. ref integrity):
[image]

As for the phisical schema, does this include the integrity rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Three-level **ANSI-SPARC Architecture**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-SPARC_Architecture) aka [three schema approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_schema_approach):

- An **external schema** is the database (with metadata including constraints) as seen by some user, a view of the conceptual schema.
- The **conceptual schema** is the database (with metatdata including constraints) per se, for an enterprise.
- The **internal schema** is the implementation.

Typically an ER diagram would not considered detailed enough to be an external schema or conceptual schema.

You may be confusing these with [Conceptual, logical and physical **data models**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_data_model) in [data modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_modeling). (Those very wiki links are themselves confused about ANSI/SPARC.)

- A **conceptual model** is informal and/or incomplete. Eg an ER diagram.
- A **logical model** is formal and in some sense complete and implementation independent. Eg approximately an ANSI/SPARC external or conceptual schema.
- A **physical model** is implementation. Eg approximately an ANSI/SPARC internal schema.

*However* there is very little agreement about just how detailed and abstract logical and physical models are. Or for that matter conceptual models. Or how these models correspond to ANSI/SPARC schemas. Eg whether an arbitrary SQL index is internal/physical or can be part of a user's/DBA's external/internal/logical interface.

See [What are Conceptual, Logical and Physical Data Models?](http://blog.infoadvisors.com/index.php/articles/what-are-conceptual-logical-and-physical-data-models/) and its link [Conceptual, Logical, Physical: Clearing the Confusion](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5021/).

From the point of view of the relational model and ANSI/SPARC, a logical model (external and conceptual schema/level) should completely describe tables and their columns, constraints and application meanings. But conceptual-logical-physical presentations generally reflect a poor understanding of the relational model.

So probably your ER model is a conceptual model among conceptual-logical-physical models. Although you could take it as a (partial) description of a logical model or external or conceptual schema. And maybe your assignment itself is confused.

You are going to have to refer to whatever definitions/references your client/instructor has given you for the assignment.