# can some explain to me the The Three-Schema Architecture

Tags: database, database-design

[image]

i am beginner in database systems , could someone explain it to me

Comment: What did google & your text tell you? [ANSI-SPARC Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-SPARC_Architecture).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The three schema of the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796538/the-three-schema-of-the-database)

Answer (score 0):

The way I learned three levels was different from what you outlined.  This was back in the 1980s, so it's possible that what I learned is no longer taught.  Here it is:

The Conceptual level

This is really data analysis, not database design.  The purpose is to come up with a model that summarizes the information requirements on the proposed database.  Every value that is to be stored is an instance of an ATTRIBUTE.  An attribute describes some aspect of either an ENTITY or a RELATIONSHIP.  Relationships are associations among entities.  Entities are the fundamental objects that compose the subject matter.

You can also derive a DOMAIN for each attribute.  The domain is the set of possible values that an attribute can take on.

Entities, relationships, attributes, and domains are all discovered by studying the subject matter. The conceptual model says next to nothing about the structure of the proposed solution.  This results in a conceptual model, generally an Entity-Relationship model.

Logical Design

The first stage of design involves expressing the attributes discovered above as components of relations. A relation is made up of tuples and attributes.  The attributes are the ones discovered in the conceptual level.  The composition of relations is guided by some principle, generally normalization.

Also added here are foreign keys.  Keys serve to identify tuples in relationships, and foreign keys serve to link a tuple being referenced with another tuple that is referencing it.  Foreign keys implement relationships, discovered above at the conceptual level.  They play the same role that pointers do in graph databases.

Also added are constraints.  These are rules that limit values in attributes.  For example, the NOT NULL constraint indicates that a given value may  not be omitted.

The result is a logical model, generally a relational model.

Physical Design

At this stage, the relational model from the logical design is converted to an SQL model, and features are added that are specific to a particular DBMS product.

Relations are expressed as tables.
Indexes are added for rapid lookup.
Structures like tablespaces are added as containers for tables.
etc. etc.

The result is a physical model that has all the specs needed for building the database.

The next step would be to convert the physical model to a database creation script.

Caution:  if you are not building a relational database, creating a relational model at the second stage might not make any sense.  If you are not using an SQL database, the description of the physical model is just about completely wrong.  I put these in to cover the most common cases.

There is some overlap between all of this and your diagram, but there's a lot of divergence, too.

Comment: The question is about the ANSII-SPARC 3-schema architecture: multiple user schemas, consolidated enterprise schema, internal implementation schema.

Comment: Right.  I was conflating ANSI-SPARC with conceptual-logical-physical.  Thanks for clearing that up.