# Clarity regarding the schemas in a database

Tags: database, schema

So far I have been able to grasp the knowledge about:

**Physical schema** - how the data is stored in the database
**Conceptual schema** - describes the relationships amongst the existing entities and
**External schema** - how the data is viewed by the users.

But what I can't seem to get around is, where does **logical schema** fit in here? Or is it a synonym for one of these schemas I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different things. One is the [ANSI-SPARC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-SPARC_Architecture) of external, conceptual & internal schemas, and the other is phases/products in one approach to [data/information modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_data_model) & [information engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_engineering), conceptual, logical & physical models. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805630/3404097).