# What exactly does the three-schema architecture refer to?

Tags: database, database-schema

Sorry if the question is vague. I've been trying to learn Database Concepts on my own and I've been trying to understand this "Internal, Conceptual, External Schema Model" for quite a while, with no success.

Almost everywhere on the internet, it is stated that the internal schema refers to how data is stored, external schema refers to how the users see the database and I still don't understand what a conceptual schema refers to.

I know a bit of SQL and I've been trying to relate all this to that(correct me if that is not the right way to approach). So suppose I create a table using SQL and decide to view the contents of the table using the `SELECT * FROM table;`command. Is the output the external schema of the table?

I'm really sorry if the question doesn't make sense, but I'm unable to understand this topic.

Previous questions asking the same were not received well: [The three schema of the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796538/the-three-schema-of-the-database)

Comment: If it helps, I've been a developer for over two decades now, and I'm considered a resident expert in SQL Server. I've never heard of this, ever (and I know about mr. Codd and his models), so not knowing these concepts is, at the very least, no impediment to a successful career that involves databases. (Also, the word "schema" is overloaded enough as it is.)

Comment: Good to hear it from an expert. I saw a video and I think I've understood it now. But if you say its not very important, I won't read more on that topic for now. Thanks :)

Comment: The linked question currenly has one answer, accepted--mine. It just happens to be re a low-traffic mostly academic conceptual topic. Read it & the articles it links to. See my answer below. Also the relevant chapters of some textbooks (There are literally tens of them free online as pdf, let alone slides & courses.) Then read other presentations in that light.

Answer (score 1):

3-schema (external, conceptual & internal) & 3-tier (conceptual, logical and physical) are ways of looking at systems. It happens that they are not typically reflected clearly in language syntax & semantics. Read the linked resources in [the answer that you link to by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805630/3404097). (But beware per the answer where resources are confused.) Learn the abstract structures/organizations and when you look at systems & processes it can help you to understand and use them.

This is similar to the situation with "client-server architecture". Maybe there is a physical "server" literally wired to some other "user" computer. But maybe we just have two software modules in the same program text. It is an abstract structure/organization which we can refer to when some system's parts are related to each other that way or when they *aren't* related to each that way.

Eg SQL syntax mixes external/conceptual logical schema notions (tables with no row order queried by syntax not reflecting execution order, transactions, etc) and internal physical schema notions (indexes, query plans, storage, schedules, etc). Similarly DBMSs allow definition of what databases & tables a particular user sees defined in terms of other databases & tables--roughly corresponding to external & conceptual schemas respectively. But per above the SQL user vs DBA logical views are both mixes of non-internal & internal. SQL DDL (data definition language) doesn't clearly separate user, DBA & physical system aspects per the architecture. Nevertheless we do talk about what users can see vs what DBAs can see vs physical/storage/representation aspects.